# SharePoint on-prem AzureAD delegated access token

Tags: azure-active-directory, sharepoint-2013, adfs

We have an app registered in our AzureAD that we use to get delegated user access to our company's SharePoint sites, using implicit grant flow. It works as expected for any O365 hosted SharePoint sites associated with our tenant. But, we have on-prem SharePoint farms that are configured to authenticate with AzureAD using the following [MS described method of setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/sharepoint-on-premises-tutorial). But, when we try to get a token that is scoped for a site in the on-prem farm, we get a AADSTS500011 error.  How do we get a oAuth delegated token for these sites?

Comment: Provide the detailed error message.

Comment: @AllenWu AADSTS500011 is a error constant id. It means "The resource principal named {scoped resource} was not found in the tenant named {tenant id}"

Comment: @JohnC Are you still looking any on this question ?

Comment: @Thirgiftthub-MSFTIdentity yes, but we figured it out. When using on-prem, you must use the on-prem farm to register your app as a self-hosted SP app, then get the token using the ACS server.

Answer (score 0):

After much more development and research, in order to access the SP site on behalf of the user. Instead of creating/registering an app in AAD, you must create a self-hosted SP app and register it within the on-prem SP farm. Then your app will use the Azure Active Directory Access Control Service(ACS) to do the oAuth flow that will gain the token needed for your app to then access SP on behalf of the user.